# Why does template argument deduction failed with variadic template parameters of a std::function callback?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-function

Let's consider the following functions:

```
// run_cb_1(): Explicitly defined prototype
void run_cb_1(const std::function<void(int)> & callback, int p)
{
    callback(p);
}

// run_cb_2(): One template parameter
template <typename T>
void run_cb_2(const std::function<void(T)> & callback, const T & t)
{
    callback(t);
}

// run_cb_3(): Variable number of template parameters
template <typename ... Args>
void run_cb_3(const std::function<void(Args...)> & callback, const Args & ... args)
{
    callback(args...);
}
```

Now if I want to use these functions as follows:

```
int main()
{
    auto f = [](int a){
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    };

    run_cb_1(f, 5);      // OK

    run_cb_2(f, 5);      // KO --> I understand why
    run_cb_2<int>(f, 5); // OK

    run_cb_3(f, 5);      // KO --> I understand why
    run_cb_3<int>(f, 5); // KO --> I don't understand why...

    return 0;
}
```

I get a *"no matching function call"* with `run_cb_2()` and `run_cb_3()` while it works perfectly fine with `run_cb_1()`.

I think it behaves as expected because I did not provided the type for the template argument (since it can not be deduced trivially as it is for `run_cb_1()`).

But specifying the template type solves the problem for `run_cb_2()` (as I would expect) but not for `run_cb_3()`.

---

I know I can solve it **either** by explicitly declaring `f` as:

```
std::function<void(int)> f = [](int a){
    std::cout << a << '\n';
};
```

**or** by passing f as:

```
run_cb_2(std::function<void(int)>(f), 5);
run_cb_3(std::function<void(int)>(f), 5);
```

---

**My question is:** Why does the template argument deduction fail with `run_cb_3()` (with variadic template parameters) even when explicitly specifying the template type(s) ?

It is obvious that I missed something (maybe basic) but I don't know what it is.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, unless you need to store the function object just make the function type generic.  This way you don't take the performance hit that `std::function` introduces since it uses type erasure.

Comment: @NathanOliver Does it mean that I shall use directly `std::function<void(int)>` instead of `auto` deduction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails is because there isn't just one type the compiler can use.  When you do

```
run_cb_2<int>(f, 5);
```

The compiler looks at `run_cb_2` and sees that there is only one template parameter.  Since you've provided that it skips the deduction phase and stamps out `run_cb_2<int>`.

With

```
run_cb_3<int>(f, 5);
```

You're in a different boat.  `run_cb_3` has a variadic template parameter which means just supplying `int` is not enough to skip the deduction.  You specified the first argument, but there could be more so it goes into the argument deduction phase to figure it out.  That means it checks `callback` to make sure what it deduces there matches what it deduces for `args`.  Since the lambda is not a `std::function` it can't deduce `Args...` from it.  Once that happens the compiler stops and issues an error.

Comment: I thought specifying only one template argument should suffice to deduce that there is no other expected parameter.

Comment: @Fareanor Unfortunately it does not work that way since you can partially supply the parameter list.  The compiler will then go on to deduce the rest.  This is the exact case you get into with parameter packs as they are unbounded.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of how it can be possible to add extra args ? I can't figure it out in my head. (I know I asked the same to @Jarod42).

Comment: @Fareanor Lets say you have `std::function<void(int,double)> f = [](int a, double b){
        std::cout << a << " " << b << '\n';
    };` then you could do `run_cb_3<int>(f, 5.5, 4.1);` and it would treat `5.5` as an `int` in deduction since you specified the first parameter is a `int`.

Comment: Now I see. I thought it would lead to a mismatch between the given template argument number and the given arguments. Morality: We can partially provide the required arguments. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Fareanor You're welcome.  C++'s templates are a Turing complete language themselves so you're basically learning an entire language within a language.  It can take some time to get into the groove.  And by that I mean forever since we are still learning new things 20+ years after they were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

With `run_cb_3<int>`, you don't explicitly provide full `Args...`, just the first type; it might have other.

It is used for example in function such as `std::make_unique`:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args);
```

and

```
std::make_unique<MyObj>(var1, var2); // T = MyObj
                                     // Args... = [decltype((var1)), decltype((var2))]
```

Extra args are deduced from argument.

To force evaluation, you might use:

```
(&run_cb_3<int>)(f, 5); // OK
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00831c4c2c0bdcec)

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know that extra args could be deduced even if I have explicitly given the template argument(s).

Comment: Can you provide me an example of how it can be possible to add extra args ? I can't figure it out in my head.

Comment: I provided `make_unique` example. You have also, with your function: `std::function<void(int, char)> f2 = /*..*/; run_cb_3<int>(f2, 5, '*');` which is valid.

Comment: Yes, with your explanation and the one from @NathanOliver, I now understand. Thank you.